# Formatting JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

What is the simplest way to pretty-print a string of JSON as a string with indentation when the initial JSON string is formatted without extra spaces or line breaks?

Currently I'm running `json.loads()` and then running `json.dumps()` with `indent=2` on the result. This works, but it feels like I'm throwing a lot of compute down the drain.

Is there a more simple or efficient (built-in) way to pretty-print a JSON string? (while keeping it as valid JSON)

**Example**

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('http://spam.eggs/breakfast')
one_line_json = response.content.decode('utf-8')
pretty_json = json.dumps(json.loads(response.content), indent=2)

print(f'Original: {one_line_json}')
print(f'Pretty: {pretty_json}')
```

Output:

```
Original: {"breakfast": ["spam", "spam", "eggs"]}
Pretty: {
  "breakfast": [
    "spam", 
    "spam", 
    "eggs"
    ]
}
```

Comment: you could probably use pretty print

Comment: @SuperStew but then the output is a formatted Python object, not JSON (e.g. ``True`` vs ``true``, ``None`` vs ``null``).

Comment: You have to parse the string one way or another, and then format and print it, one way or another. I don't think `json.loads` and `json.dumps` is more expensive than any other approch, e.g. using `pprint` instead of `dumps`. Probably even faster.

Comment: @MikeScotty the moment OP invoked `json.loads()` it already transformed the JSON into a Python object.

Comment: @Idlehands and then OP invoked ``json.dumps`` on the Python object, turning it into JSON. The whole question is about JSON output. A string representation of a Python object just is not the same as JSON, though both of them are similar.

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger - Can you post a testable example for the type of page you're trying to decode? The link 'http://spam.eggs/breakfast' does not resolve. If you provide usable URL I can update my answer to reflect the cost of decoding the HTTP request.

Comment: @ScottSkiles Here's a URL with a big piece of JSON: https://www.cbcmusic.ca/Component/Playlog/GetPlaylog?stationId=96&date=2018-11-05

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**`json.dumps(obj, indent=2)` is better than `pprint` because:**

1. It is faster with the same load methodology.
2. It has the same or similar simplicity.
3. The output will produce valid JSON, whereas `pprint` will not.

**pprint_vs_dumps.py**

```
import cProfile
import json
import pprint
from urllib.request import urlopen


def custom_pretty_print():
    url_to_read = "https://www.cbcmusic.ca/Component/Playlog/GetPlaylog?stationId=96&date=2018-11-05"
    with urlopen(url_to_read) as resp:
        pretty_json = json.dumps(json.load(resp), indent=2)
    print(f'Pretty: {pretty_json}')


def pprint_json():
    url_to_read = "https://www.cbcmusic.ca/Component/Playlog/GetPlaylog?stationId=96&date=2018-11-05"
    with urlopen(url_to_read) as resp:
        info = json.load(resp)
    pprint.pprint(info)


cProfile.run('custom_pretty_print()')
>>> 71027 function calls (42309 primitive calls) in 0.084 seconds

cProfile.run('pprint_json()')
>>>164241 function calls (140121 primitive calls) in 0.208 seconds
```

Thanks @tobias_k for pointing out my errors along the way.

Comment: But is this any faster than using `json.dumps`? I seriously doubt that. Also, the result may not be valid JSON.

Comment: Ah good question, he did specify more "efficient" didn't he. I may have incorrectly interpreted this as fewer lines of code. I'd have to profile to compare efficiency directly.

Comment: It's not even fewer lines of code, as you just replace one function call with another. If anything, you don't need the `indent` parameter, but as I said: Invalid JSON for things like `True`, `False`, `None`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k. I see what you mean about the cost to decode. And the cProfile isn't a one-to-one comparison with OP's example. Unfortunately, 'http://spam.eggs/breakfast' does not resolve into a usable example.

Comment: Sorry, but you are comparing apples and oranges here. If you do a timing analysis, please do it properly. Why is loading the JSON from the URL part of the method you are timing? This will take most time and is irrelevant for the question. Also, you are using two different methods for loading the content, skewing the results even further. _Also_, in your first example you are pretty-printing just the raw JSON string, _not_ the JSON dictionary. Then, using `pprint` you only print _part_ of the full JSON object. If you load the JSON just once, then `json.dumps` will come out a bit faster.

Comment: @tobias_k - I understand this is flawed, but how can we compare this: ```Also, in your first example you are pretty-printing just the raw JSON string, not the JSON dictionary. ```?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183209/discussion-between-scott-skiles-and-tobias-k).

Comment: I think this is the key issue I am missing (apples vs. oranges): ```what's the simplest way to format it as a pretty string with indentation?``` - I feel like the pprint answer is fine, because it is printing it as a string with indentation. Is it required that the output is also valid JSON? It does not seem to be a requirement in the question, but rather a restriction placed on the answer post-hoc.

Comment: @tobias_k - Please see updates. I think I resolved your doubts and I think that the profiling DOES make sense, because the json.dumps() and json.loads() calls are necessary to utilize the `indent=2` parameter.

Comment: The call to `json.loads` in necessary in _both_ cases. `pprint.pprint(json_obj)` with `json_obj` being a string does _not_ format the JSON string anyway close to how OP wants it. If anything, it will only break lines at spaces, which is also not valid JSON.

Comment: Okay, I see that now. I left out the ```json.load``` used in the example.

Comment: @tobias_k - Are you certain that OP needs a valid JSON object? I do not understand why this so important when he asked for a string.

Comment: Looking back, I guess I wasn't explicit, but I was in fact looking for a result with valid JSON. Hoping to write out files I can load as JSON, but also take a glance through easily.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for following up and glad we could get something that works.

Answer (score 3):

I think for a true JSON object print, it's probably as good as it gets.  `timeit(number=10000)` for the following took about `5.659214497s`:

```
import json
d = {   
        'breakfast': [
            'spam', 'spam', 'eggs', 
            {
                'another': 'level', 
                'nested': [
                    {'a':'b'}, 
                    {'c':'d'}
                ]
            }
        ], 
        'foo': True,
        'bar': None
    }
s = json.dumps(d)
q = json.dumps(json.loads(s), indent=2)
print(q)
```

I tried with `pprint`, but it actually wouldn't print the pure JSON string unless it's converted to a Python `dict`, which loses your `true`, `null` and `false` etc valid JSON as mentioned in the other answer.  As well it doesn't retain the order in which the items appeared, so it's not great if order is important for readability.

Just for fun I whipped up the following function:

```
def pretty_json_for_savages(j, indentor='  '):
    ind_lvl = 0
    temp = ''
    for i, c in enumerate(j):
        if c in '{[':
            print(indentor*ind_lvl + temp.strip() + c)
            ind_lvl += 1
            temp = ''
        elif c in '}]':
            print(indentor*ind_lvl + temp.strip() + '\n' + indentor*(ind_lvl-1) + c, end='')
            ind_lvl -= 1
            temp = ''
        elif c in ',':
            print(indentor*(0 if j[i-1] in '{}[]' else ind_lvl) + temp.strip() + c)
            temp = ''
        else:
            temp += c
    print('')

# {
#   "breakfast":[
#     "spam",
#     "spam",
#     "eggs",
#     {
#       "another": "level",
#       "nested":[
#         {
#           "a": "b"
#         },
#         {
#           "c": "d"
#         }        
#       ]      
#     }    
#   ],
#   "foo": true,
#   "bar": null
# }
```

It prints pretty alright, and unsurprisingly it took a whooping `16.701202023s` to run in `timeit(number=10000)`, which is *3 times as much* as a `json.dumps(json.loads())` would get you.  It's probably not worthwhile to build your own function to achieve this unless you spend some time to optimize it, and with the lack of a `builtin` for the same, it's probably best you stick with your gun since your efforts will most likely give diminishing returns.